# Does subrole exist?

Tags: users

I want to know if "subrole" exists. Let me explain : I need to show different content based on user role.

1. Big role1

   - Subrole 1
   - Subrole 2
2. Big role2

   - Subrole 1
   - Subrole 2

Where subroles 1/2 are the same from bigrole1 to bigrole2.

How can I implements several level role ?

Comment: What would the benefit be over just having a flat hierarchy of roles?

Comment: Don't create main role, just create sub roles as a main role. like your roles wil be subrole1 and subrole2.

Comment: In a view, I have to show the role of the current user, if I choose "Big role 1 -> subrole1", it will show "big role 1, subrole". But I only want to show "subrole"

Comment: There isn't much point to this... roles hold permissions, a user can be assigned multiple roles. Giving a user both "sub roles" (or just flat out roles) equates to "Big Role" which you don't need to create. In short, core already does this. You might need to step back and think about the roles you are making, or need to make, and what their ACLs are.

Comment: @MorganTartreau are the "roles" needed for access control, or do you want to add a form of classification for your users? In Drupal jargon a role is meant to grant a certain permission, and somehow I've the impression that you only want to display the information and use it to filter content. If that's the case, you can use a taxonomy, in which you can define your hierarchy, and "label" your users and filter the content accordingly.